# Unity Ads in Libgdx game

Tags: libgdx, unityads

I want to implement Unity ads into Android game which is created with Libgdx engine.

I searched for solutions on net but i didn't find anything useful, so every help is welcome: Code samples, links with explanations...

Answer (score 1):

Unity provides instructions on integrating Unity ads into any Android application built in the Eclipse IDE [here](http://unityads.unity3d.com/help/monetization/integration-guide-android).

Unity ads are not specific to a specific graphics/application framework, so they should work with the provided instructions for any Android app. You might have to wrap your LibGDX in a bit of native Android UI, using the second answer [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/57702/libgdx-with-android-ui).

Comment: I already saw this links. 
Unity's Integration guide is for native Android and not for cross platform engine. I also find some instructions for adding Admob ads in Libgdx and i know that i need to do something like that for Unity ads so i would like to find some instructions for that.